# Facebook PHP SDK get always 0

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I want to work with Facebook on server side. Therefore I use Facebook SDK API.
I used tutorial to quick start and added curl options which fix often problems.

But getUser return 0 again. I made print_r($*SESSION). And see there are fb*_[FACEBOOK_APP_ID]_state var. Facebook redirects me back to my page with no errors, but getUser is 0.

```
define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID',"387123884707291");
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET',"REMOVED");

$user = null;

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
    'cookie' => true   
));

Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = 0;
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 0;  
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT] = 30; 


$user = $facebook->getUser(); 

print_r($_SESSION); //here line!

if($user == 0) {

    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));   
    $content =  "<script> top.location.href='".$login_url."'</script>";

    echo "bb";

} else 
     echo "logined";
die;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I have solved issue by enabling "Facebook application" tab (see screenshot).

[image]